# How to return a list of elements that were used in Average as well as their Average

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I'm developing an asp.net web app using Entity Framework Core. I have a list of Students, Subjects and Marks. I need a table with subject name, all marks for a particular subject and average mark.

I can do that with two different queries. But the table I'm putting all this in should be sortable and it's hard to sort when the table is formed from two different sources. I try to come out with a single linq query to resolve my problem.

```
Subject | List of Marks | Average
```

The DTO class that I try to pass to the view is as follows:

```
    public class Marks
    {
        public string Name;
        public List<int> Mark;
        public double Avg;
    }
```

The linq i came up with is the following:

```
            var gradesIQ = _context.Gradebooks
                    .Include(s => s.Student)
                    .Where(s => s.LessonDate.Month == month && s.LessonDate.Year == year
                        && s.Student.GradeId == gradeId && s.StudentId == studentId && s.Mark != "0")
                    .Select(s => new
                    {
                        Name = s.Subject.Name,
                        Mark = s.Mark
                    })
                    .GroupBy(s => s.Name)
                    .Select(g => new Marks
                    {
                        Name = g.Key,
                        Avg = g.Average(s => Convert.ToInt32(s.Mark)),
                        Mark = ??? //should be List<int> Mark
                    });
```

Please help me make a single linq for the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot retrieve group items with LINQ to Entities. It is SQL limitation.

Since you need all elements, you can do grouping on the client side without loosing performance and resources.

```cs
var gradesIQ = _context.Gradebooks
    .Where(s => s.LessonDate.Month == month && s.LessonDate.Year == year
        && s.Student.GradeId == gradeId && s.StudentId == studentId && s.Mark != "0")
    .Select(s => new
    {
        Name = s.Subject.Name,
        Mark = Convert.ToInt32(s.Mark)
    })
    .AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(s => s.Name)
    .Select(g => new Marks
    {
        Name = g.Key,
        Avg = g.Average(s => s.Mark),
        Mark = g.Select(x => x.Mark).ToList()
    });
```